# Is tree datatype what I need in this case ? [TicTacToe Game]

Tags: python

I'm trying myself on an algorithm that plays ticTacToe against itself and learns out of the winning conditions. When it wins, it checks again all the moves it made and increases the probability for the next time the same situation comes.
I never did something like that before. So my idea is that I need every combination of possible Moves.

In the first round the PC has to chose from a list of 9 elements, each representing one of the tiles on the game. Then the other player can chose from 8. But: there has to be 9 different lists player two can chose from. When player one chose number 2 , player two is allowed to chose from the list of elements which does not include number 2.

So I need in the first row 1 list of 9 Elements. In the Second I need 9 lists of 8 elements each and so on.

This becomes pretty big, so I need to create those combinations automatically.
My idea was to create lists which contains either more lists or the elements to chose from.  Then I can navigate through those lists to tell the player out of which list (or path in a big list of lists) to chose from. I‘m not really sure if there is an easy way to do this, especially the creating of those lists. I couldn’t find a way yet. Then I saw the tree datatype, which seems to be powerful, but I’m not sure if this is the right one that I search for. Hope you can give me advice

Edit: to make it clear, I know there is this minmax algorithm etc. What I wanted to do is let the game play a lot against itself and Let it find their own way in learning. Just by getting the result if he won or not.

Comment: You can do it with a tree, of course. There is a very finite number of moves in TicTacToe and they are easily capturable as trees. But you have to consider that the first choice is not between 9 options but between 3 (middle, long side, corner) and the second one is also not between 8, as mirror symmetrical choices are identical.

Comment: You are right for the first one , but for the second move the symmetry is lost because there is already a move done wich should affect the choice the pc makes

Comment: Yes, it does. But if your first choice was a corner, the near long-sides are equivalent, as well as the far long-sides and the near corners. So, you don't have 8 but 5 choices. If your first choice was the center, you only have 2 options: corner or long side. (I drew a complete tree by hand, once. It's not that big if you consider symmetries).

Comment: Well I think i know what you mean. But that represents just the current state of the board . I also need to trace back when wich move was done , especially the order is interesting. And i don’t fully understand how the symmetry helps with that

Comment: The symmetry mainly helps in adding several new nodes with each turn. If a decision is made to tick a box, all equivalent boxes should be ticked in the decision tree. So, if X marks the lower left corner and O marks the lower long side, this is equivalent to the situation where X marked any other corner and O marked an adjacent long-side. If you figure out how to generalize this situation, the tree gets filled faster and the learning is more efficient.

Comment: Well that’s true, thanks for the advice but I guess this has to be the next step. Can you tell me if this would work with just lists in lists and navigate through them all ?

Comment: That could work, yes. If you assign each box an index, all lists will have a length of exactly 9 and the lowest level holds the information on whether the game was won or lost.

Comment: I am not certain what is the question, but...

... If you are only interested in TicTacToe, the number of combinations is 9!=362880 (not deducing games related by symmetry).
So you could build any simple algorithm to explore all of them.

... If you want this as a basis for a generic game that has a much larger number of combinations (possibly infinite), please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you plan to follow might be considered as an Ant Colonization Algorithm. As your description points out the idea is to explore available paths according to some heuristic and backtracking the path followed to increase/decrease the probability of that same path to be taken again in subsequent iterations, effectively weighting the graph edges (the state tree of TicTacToe in this case). At the end of the process the winning paths will have a greater weight than the loosing ones which would allow your engine to play TicTacToe well by following the heaviest edges. Here are some links if you're interested: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms), [seminar slides](http://mat.uab.cat/%7Ealseda/MasterOpt/ACO_Intro.pdf).

IMO the nature of the algorithm *requires* some kind of tree/graph data structure to ease backtracking and neighbor discovery and I would personally go for that instead of using lists of lists. To that effect you may try the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) library, for example.

Separately I agree with @martin-wettstein comments that taking advantage of board symmetries would reduce the number of board states to be considered and would improve performance at the cost of a slightly more complicated logic.

Indeed I implemented the same approach as you some time ago and it was really fun, so good luck at it.